# Positioning Popup GWT

Tags: gwt

How Can i position Popup at the mouse clicked position in GWT. I tried using the getX, and getY on the flextable and set the Popup to that position but that isn't working.

Answer (score 2):

Quick example:

```java
final RootLayoutPanel rootLayoutPanel = RootLayoutPanel.get();

final FocusPanel focusPanel = new FocusPanel();

/* just to make the clickable area visible */
focusPanel.getElement().getStyle().setBackgroundColor("red");

rootLayoutPanel.add(focusPanel);


final PopupPanel popupPanel = new PopupPanel();
popupPanel.add(new Label("Popup"));
popupPanel.show();

focusPanel.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

  @Override
  public void onClick(final ClickEvent event) {
    final int left = event.getClientX();
    final int top = event.getClientY();

    popupPanel.setPopupPosition(left, top);
  }
});
```

Notes:

- Make sure to show the PopupPanel after adding the focusPanel, otherwise it will be behind the focusPanel.
- I'm using the RootLayoutPanel here, but you could also work relative to a different element (use `left = event.getRelativeX(myContextElem);` etc.)
- If you don't want to use a FocusPanel (which has ClickHandlers), you could alternatively use a MouseDownHandler, but in that case you then need to call `sinkEvents(Event.ONMOUSEDOWN)`.